# Proxy Plesk through apache alias

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, alias

I have a VPS that I installed Plesk into. It has an external IP but only ports 22,80,443 are allowed through the firewall. Plesk uses port 8443 so currently the only way to access it is to tunnel through SSH.

Is it possible to use a Alias to proxy to the plesk panel? Similar to the way phpmyadmin works. All articles I've read so far have you setup a domain, subdomain, create a vhost.conf file and forward through that. I'd prefer to access the server directly using https://Server_IP/plesk

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm not au fait with plesk, but yes it may be possible that you cannot use it through an alias. Why? It depends on how it handles it links. It may expect to be the only thing on a domain and if it does, the links it generates may be absolute links. i.e. links start with a "/"

Your safest bet is to use a domain name. If you're worried about potential problems with DNS, you can always stick an entry into your hosts file on your own machine to overcome DNS problem if / when they should arise.

However, you can always try it:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass        /myalias/ https://1.2.3.4:8443/
ProxyPassReverse /myalias/ https://1.2.3.4:8443/
```

Comment: Almost there. I've added that bit of code to the /etc/httpd/conf/zzSA...conf.

But I'm getting a file not found login.php3 error.

Comment: This could be because the Plesk is simply not setup to do such a thing, I'm afraid I don't know enough about it, but as explained above, it's a distinct possibility (most apps wouldn't be!)